# setting up sql column for multiple values to store check box values

Tags: php, sql, forms, checkbox

I want to store at the lowest 1 and most 9 check box values to my database.

What value do I need to make the column in sql for the values to insert into it.

Also should I not be able to grab each value with just the name="value" ?

php:

```
    $description = pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME);  
    $filename = date('Ymdhis').".pdf"; 
    $username = $_SESSION['username']; 


       $sql = "INSERT INTO documents (id, userid, description, name, date) VALUES (NULL, {$_SESSION['id']}, '{$description}' ,'{$filename}', NOW())"; 
  $success = mysql_query($sql);  
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO sprintvisioncc (first_name, last_name, email, telephone, truck_number, truck_mileage, market, carrier, site_number, time_in, time_out, stany_by, foreman, climber1, climber2, resources, issued, issues, root, action, release, materials, remaining, close_out, lat, longitude, comments, job_completion) VALUES  ( '" . $_POST['first_name'] . "', '" . $_POST['last_name'] . "', '" . $_POST['email'] . "', '" . $_POST['telephone']. "', '" . $_POST['truck_number'] . "', '" . $_POST['truck_mileage'] . "', '" . $_POST['market'] . "', '" . $_POST['carrier'] . "', '" .$_POST['site_number'] . "', '" . $_POST['time_in'] . "', '" . $_POST['time_out'] . "', '" . $_POST['stand_by'] . "', '" . $_POST['foreman']  . "', '" . $_POST['climber1']  . "', '" . $_POST['climber2']  . "', '" . $_POST['resources']  . "', '" . $_POST['issued']  . "', '" . $_POST['issues']  . "', '" . $_POST['root']  . "', '" . $_POST['action']  . "', '" . $_POST['release']  . "', '" . $_POST['materials']  . "', '" . $_POST['remaining'] . "', '" . $_POST['close_out']  . "', '" . $_POST['lat']  . "', '" . $_POST['longitude'] . "', '" . $_POST['comments'] . "', '" . $_POST['job_completion'] . "')";
 $success2 = mysql_query($sql2);
```

Form:
    
     
      Closeouts Provided *

```
<tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
 <td valign="top">
<label>Pre Alarm Screen Shots</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out" value="Post Alarm Shots">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
<label>Post Alam Screen Shots</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out" value="Pre Alarm Shots">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
 <td valign="top">
<label>Pre Photos</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out" value="Pre Photos">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
<label>Post Photos</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out" value="Post Photos">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
 <td valign="top">
<label>Pre Sweeps</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out" value="Pre Sweeps">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
<label>Post Sweeps</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out" value="Post Sweeps">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
 <td valign="top">
<label>Pre Fiber Test</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out" value="Pre Fiber Test">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
<label>Post Fiber Test</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out" value="Post Fiber Test">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
 <td valign="top">
<label>NTP1 Form</span></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out" value="NTP1 Form">
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: well one your checkboxes' names need to use array notation at the end of their names otherwise they will overwrite one another and you will only ever get one value, `name="close_out[]"`

Comment: how U want the computer understand any one of checkbox U want

Comment: ok please show me the best way to do this.. I have never had to enter check boxes in a table like this before.

Comment: When you decide to store multiple pieces of data in a single field, you should rethink your DB approach

Comment: U must put something to have different names for these checkboxes

Comment: ok so basically they will each have their own column on sql? each one a boolean?

Comment: That is the way I would do it... storing arrays of values in a field will only prove to be cumbersome.

Comment: so select boolean then give it a value of 0? or null or what?

Answer (score 0):

form should be like this

```
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
<label>Post Sweeps</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out1" value="Post Sweeps">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
 <td valign="top">
<label>Pre Fiber Test</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out2" value="Pre Fiber Test">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
<label>Post Fiber Test</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out3" value="Post Fiber Test">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
 <td valign="top">
<label>NTP1 Form</span></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="close_out4" value="NTP1 Form">
 </td>
</tr>
```

and php should be like this

```
for($i=1;$i>=4;$i++)
{
if(isset($_POST["close_out".$i])) 
  ${"close_out".$i}=1;
else
  ${"close_out".$i}=0;
}
```

and use   `$close_out1,..,$close_out4` to enter to database

Comment: so select boolean then give it a value of 0? or null or what?

Comment: U can change it to null if U want or for example yes and no

Comment: see what U want to save at database

Comment: im saying so if i set it to null and then just dont put anything in the values box? it would just be null unless a box is checked? then in the values of the check box form make all values 1?

Comment: no this will be at the script i mean after submit the form by php file :)

Comment: i read online to make them true or false. use bit... so if i use bit to i have to add anything to the value field?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49194/discussion-between-robert-and-nichodiaz)